# Replace and Iterate over x- and y-axis of multi-dimensional np.matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have written the following script:

```
import numpy as np

d = 0.05  
limits = np.arange(0, 0.5, d)
matrix = np.zeros([limits.shape[0], limits.shape[0]])
matrix[:, 0] = limits
matrix[0, :] = limits
```

This gives me the following matrix:
[image]

How can I make sure that the values in the first column and first row are the "index"-values? So instead of [0,1,2,...,9] there should be [0, 0.05, ...0.45]

Thank you

Comment: They are the "index" values. You haven't said what you're actually viewing this in. The question is about whatever that is displaying the array, not numpy

Comment: Hi okay, but `for x in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    print(matrix[x, 0])`
doesn't give [0, 0.05, 0.1, ... , 0.45]. Why is that the case?

Comment: Yes it does. Something is missing from your question otherwise.

Comment: `print(limits)` to see what you are assigning to the first row and column of the matrix.  That's exactly what I see in the image.